# ZIP file created with Python treated as virus by browsers

Tags: python, odoo, zip, virus

I am creating a ZIP file with python ZipFile library. It contains 4 .txt files the content of each is just a string with some data for a report. It also contains 4 .pdf files which are created from a HTML template converted to pdf with `wkhtmtopdf`. The ZIP is then stored in binary in a PostgreSQL database. Then it is provided to the user for download. The problem I experience is that when the download is initiated most browsers treat the file as harmful (virus).

```
    zip_stream = io.BytesIO()
    with ZipFile(zip_stream, 'w') as myzip:
        myzip.writestr('file1.txt', report_data['file1_txt'])
        myzip.writestr('file2.txt', report_data['file2_txt'])
        myzip.writestr('file3.txt', report_data['file3_txt'])
        myzip.writestr('file4.txt', report_data['file4_txt'])
        myzip.writestr('file1.pdf', wkhtmltopdf.render_qweb_pdf(report_data['file1_html'])
        myzip.writestr('file2.pdf', wkhtmltopodf.render_qweb_pdf(report_data['file2_html'])
        myzip.writestr('file3.pdf', wkhtmltodpf.render_qweb_pdf(report_data['file3_html'])
        myzip.writestr('file4.pdf',wkhtmltopdf.render_qweb_pdf(report_data['file4_html'])

    values = {
        'name': 'report.zip',
        'type': 'binary',
        'mimetype': 'application/zip',
        'public': False,
        'db_datas': base64.b64encode(zip_stream.getvalue())
    }
    # Writing to database using custom ORM.
    attachment_id = self.env['ir.attachment'].create(values)
    # Creating download URL:
    download_url = '/web/content/' + str(attachment_id.id) + '?download=True'
    base_url = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('web.base.url')
```

Comment: Did you check the magic number for the zip file?

Comment: The magic number is to check if is actually a Zip file, right?
It matches the following which means it is ZIP: \x50\x4b\x03\x04